# Form submit redirection using header with variable included

Tags: php, forms, redirect

I have a form that posts to another page on this page it processes the form and redirects me but what i am trying to do is add a variable to the url

The line that redirects me

```
header('Location: landing.php?url=$url');
```

You see im trying to go to `landing.php?url=the-domain-thats-entered-into-the-form`

It will not work but if I remove the above line and put the following after the code

```
<?  echo "$url"; ?>
```

it shows up fine, this is leading me to think i am missing something basic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variables under single quotes will not be parsed. Try like this [Use double quotes instead]

```
header("Location: landing.php?url=$url");
       ^---  Use Double Quotes   -----^
```